# How can I represent collection of distant but visit-able stars while using minimal resources?

Tags: unity, optimization, spatial-partitioning

I have recently started to plan a project in Unity that will be for Android. I have a database that consists of over 150,000 stars (may trim this down if I/O cripples the overhead). The game will hopefully consist of a free-to-explore universe creating the illusion that the user is flying in a realistic representation of the stars.

My biggest concern at the moment is how do I create a realistic environment with these starts, while keeping the resource impact on the phone to a minimum? Some people mentioned using octrees, would this be wise?

This is my first game that I am looking to create so any help would be much appreciated to this novice!

Comment: The first advice I can give you is to search for the rules of the game development sites you happen to aim at taking part in. For instance, this site's [help center](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help) would easily show you that in its current state, your question(s) does not fit this site. You are infringing many rules by asking 1) more than one question at a time; 2) asking "too broad" questions, 3) asking "primarily opinion based" questions and 4) asking "how to get started" questions. All these are out of the scope here. So I advice you reformulate your post after reading the site rules

Comment: My apologies, where would you recommend posting such a wall of text for discussion?

Comment: No problem, I realized you were in need of orientation about it. A nice place for you to have more open discussions is at the gamedev.net forums. Then, you can bring your future more specific, limited scope and non-fully subjective questions here. Using both sites properly and in combination can prove to be very helpful, as you shall see. Best of luck!